# How Can I Change Native Resolution by HDMI?

Tags: hdmi, resolution

I have a monitor which supports 1366x768 resolution. But I want to change it to 1920x1080 pixel. Whenever I add a custom resolution in Ubuntu, my monitor warns me that only 1366x768 higher resolution is supported. Can I change this using a device or HDMI cable.

Answer (score 1):

Native resolution is the number of physical pixels your monitor has. So if you would magnify your monitor's screen, you could count that it has 1366 pixels on its horizontal edge and 768 pixels on the vertical edge.

You can't change the native resolution because the monitor doesn't physically have more pixels.

HDMI has nothing to do with it.